# To position a div after a fixed div if the fixed div height changes dynamically, css issue

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a `position: fixed` div that loads a dynamic image from an external source, the image height changes every time it loads.
Now I need to position the next `div` immediately from where the first div ends.

Have tried by getting the height during runtime but sometimes it takes time to load and the height sent is not proper.

Is there any CSS solution to it.

Comment: Please post code snippets of what you have done so far.

Comment: You can use the image's `onload` event handler to defer your attempt to get the dimensions: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XUL/Attribute/image.onload

Comment: What do you mean by “fixed div”? Do you mean the `div` has the style `position: fixed`?

Comment: @RoryO'Kane I mean the div having style position:fixed

Answer (score -1):

Theres many ways to do it, the most optimal would be to use floats (float:left;)

```css
div{
  float:left;
}
.img{
  background-color:red;
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
}

.div{
  background-color:lime;
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="img">Dynamic Image</div>
<div class="div">Div next to it</div>
```

Comment: The `div` in your answer does not have `position: fixed` as mentioned in the question title, so this solution is inapplicable. Also, whenever you want to put items horizontally next to each other, [flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Flexbox) produces more consistent behavior than `float`, and it has good browser support by now.

Comment: flex are not supported by ie9 or lower

OP never mentionned something about position:fixed
having a "fixed div" dsnt mean position:fixed ...